# Find if a string DOES NOT contain another string

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out a way to detect if a string DOES NOT contain another string.

Right now I can use strpos like so:

```
<?php

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.wra.net/calendar/calendar_4.ics");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
        $page = curl_exec($ch);
        $page = explode("BEGIN:VEVENT", $page);
        echo "<pre>";
        for ($i=1; $page[$i] != ""; $i++) { 
            $res = explode("SUMMARY:", $page[$i]);
            $res = explode("DESCRIPTION:", $res[1]);
            if (strpos($res[0], "Gallery") !== false) {
                //do nothing
            } else {
                //echo "BEGIN:VEVENT".$page[$i];
                echo $res[0].PHP_EOL;
            }
        }
        echo "</pre>";
    ?>
```

but obviously that's not a preferred way to do it.

Anyone know of a function or workaround that is cleaner?

Comment: *Returns the **position of where the needle exists** relative to the beginning of the haystack string (independent of offset). Also note that string positions start at 0, and not 1. Returns FALSE if the needle was not found.*

Comment: I understand that they start at 0. The first entry in the iCal file is a "header" of sorts, setting the title and date created of the calendar.

Comment: Can you explain to me then how `strpos() !== true` is going to get you anywhere? Because that would *always* be true.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, I guess it was just some weird brainglitch that I had. I'd been using strpos to find if the string had any position of another string via strpos, and it's late so I assumed strpos would work backward.

What can I use to find if the string DOES NOT contain something?

Comment: @Marty Actually it would always be false, `strpos()` only returns integers and false. So boolean true would never happen.

Comment: @NickJ Yes, so `strpos() !== true` would always be true given it can never return the boolean true, right?

Comment: @marty lol my bad, sorry about that. Misread it as `===` for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `false === strpos( $res[0], "Gallery" )` to test for values in `$res[0]` that do not contain "Gallery". The [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) function will return `false` if there are no matches, but `0` if it is the first thing in the string, so you must use `=== false` and not just `== false`, and any non-`false` result indicates that there was a match.

```
if ( false === strpos( $res[0], "Gallery" ) ){
    // does not contain Gallery
} else {
    // does contain Gallery
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`strpos` returns and integer representing the place of the first ocurrence if a match is encountered not a boolean true value. Since you are using strict type comparison it's not meeting the condition.

Answer (score 0):

For clarity:

```
function containsString($input)
{
    return strpos($input) !== false;
}

function doesNotContainString($input)
{
    return strpos($input) === false;
}
```